# RAND gives #n/a

Tags: excel, random

in excel I have

```
Sex   Probability     Cumulative Prob
M     80%             80%
F     20%             100%
```

These are in a sheet called probability of Client and run from cells `E1:G3`.

In another worksheet i have put the below formula in. Most of the time the result is `#N/A` with the occasional 'M'. How can i choose this so either M or F is picked in line with the probability above.

```
=INDEX('Probability of client'!$E$2:$E$3,MATCH(RAND(),'Probability of client'!$G$2:$G$3))
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I gather your question correctly, you simply want an randomized output of 80% M and 20% F ?

The simplest approach for that would be

```
=IF(RAND()>='Probability of Client'!$F$2,'Probability of Client'!$E$3,'Probability of Client'!$E$2)
```

Comment: Very clever indeed!

Answer (score 0):

The way i added the data in the cumulative prob column was wrong I should have started with 0% then sum'd from there.

The date should have been

[image]

Comment: Rather change you question than putting this relevant information in an answer :)